# SQL Selecting rows with not the same condition for all

Tags: sql

I have to create SQL query that select persons datas. Every person has several grades and I have to select first by time for everyone. I don't know how do it because conditional is different for every person. Below is my current code which doesn't works.

```
SELECT s.sol_last_name,
    g.grade_name,
    MIN(sg.sol_grade_date_from)
FROM [dbo].[dim_s####] AS s
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[fact_s####_grade] AS sg ON s.sol_key = sg.sol_grade_sollers_key
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[dim_grade] AS g ON g.grade_key = sg.sol_grade_grade_key
GROUP BY s.sol_last_name,
        g.grade_name
HAVING MIN(sg.sol_grade_date_from) = sg.sol_grade_date_from
```

Comment: Do you mind adding some data to the question and the expected result as a table? Could you also explain in your question what are the different conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the earliest date in a subquery, and then inner join there:

```
SELECT s.sol_last_name,
    g.grade_name,
    sg.sol_grade_date_from
FROM [dbo].[dim_s####] AS s

    INNER JOIN ( 
             select sol_grade_grade_key
             ,min(sol_grade_date_from) as sol_grade_date_
             from from [dbo].[dim_grade] 
             GROUP BY sol_grade_grade_key) AS g 
    ON g.grade_key = sg.sol_grade_grade_key

    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[fact_s####_grade] AS sg 
    ON s.sol_key = sg.sol_grade_sollers_key
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Common Table Expression` (cte) to save some typing. Then do a `NOT EXISTS` to return a row only if same sol_last_name has no older grade.

```
WITH CTE (sol_last_name, grade_name, grade_date_from) AS
(
SELECT s.sol_last_name,
    g.grade_name,
    sg.sol_grade_date_from
FROM [dbo].[dim_s####] AS s
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[fact_s####_grade] AS sg ON s.sol_key = sg.sol_grade_sollers_key
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[dim_grade] AS g ON g.grade_key = sg.sol_grade_grade_key
)
select sol_last_name, grade_name, grade_date_from
from cte as t1
where not exists (select 1 from cte t2
                  where t2.sol_last_name = t1.sol_last_name
                    and t2.grade_date_from < t2.grade_date_from)
```